# Why $\left\| \begin{pmatrix} A &0\\ 0 &0 \end{pmatrix}\right\|=\|A\|$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space, with inner product $\langle\cdot\;, \;\cdot\rangle$ and the norm $\|\cdot\|$ and let $\mathcal{L}(E)$ the algebra of all operators on $E$.

> Let $A\in\mathcal{L}(E)$. I want to prove that
>   $$\left\| \begin{pmatrix}
> A &0\\
> 0 &0
> \end{pmatrix}\right\|=\|A\|.$$
>   Here $\begin{pmatrix}
> A &0\\
> 0 &0
> \end{pmatrix}\in \mathcal{L}(E\oplus E)$.

It is well-known that
$$\left\| \begin{pmatrix}
A &0\\
0 &0
\end{pmatrix}\right\|\leq \left\| \begin{pmatrix}
\|A\| &0\\
0 &0
\end{pmatrix}\right\|=\|A\|.$$
I'm facing difficulties to prove the converse inequality.

Comment: You need to explain what the 'matrix' is? A map from what to what?

Comment: Let $x\in E$ so that $\|A x\|≥ (\|A\|-\epsilon)\|x\|$ for some $\epsilon$. Then $\begin{pmatrix}A&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\0\end{pmatrix}$ gets you $\epsilon$ close to $\|A\|$. You can do this for every $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} Ax \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\|\begin{bmatrix} Ax \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \|= \|Ax\|$, the result follows immediately from the definition of the operator norm.

Answer (score 1):

The equality can be directly proved
\begin{align*}
\left\| \begin{pmatrix}
A &0\\
0 &0
\end{pmatrix}\right\| &= \sup_{\substack{a\in E^2\\\|a\|^2=1}} \left\| \begin{pmatrix}
A &0\\
0 &0
\end{pmatrix}\cdot a\right\|\\
&= \sup_{\substack{x\in E,y\in E\\\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2=1}} \left\| \begin{pmatrix}
A &0\\
0 &0
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y
\end{pmatrix}\right\|\\
&= \sup_{\substack{x\in E\\\|x\|^2=1}} \left\| \begin{pmatrix}
A &0\\
0 &0
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
x\\0
\end{pmatrix}\right\|\\
&= \sup_{\substack{x\in E\\\|x\|^2=1}} \left\| A\cdot x\right\|\\
&=\|A\|
\end{align*}